# Get data from multiple tables while editing in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

In MVC,I have designed a view where I am able to bind the datas from multiple tables i.e, I'm getting 
different records from 3 different tables which I am displaying in my Index.

Now on click of edit I want to send those datas to the edit view and this is where I am facing trouble.In my earlier forms,I was able to do this with **db.find()** which refers to only one table and based on its composite keys I was able to find all the datas corresponding to that table.

I want to get records from 3 tables on click of edit which I am successfully able to bind in my Index view.

Below is my Controller code:

```
objMyObj.MyModel = db.TableName.find(allcompositekeyshere);
```

According to me,I wont be able to get records from multiple tables with db.find as it will refer to only one table.So,For this I want some different logic.
Any help would be appreciated.Thanks in advance..

Below is my linq query with which I am able to get all the records from city table along with country name from country table and state name from state table.

```
return objSvc.GetCityIndexData().Select(ct =>
                    new CityInputModel()
                    {
                        CityID = ct.CityID,
                        StateID = ct.StateID,
                        CountryID = ct.CountryID,
                        Name = ct.Name,
                        CountryName = ct.CountryName,
                        StateName = ct.StateName
                    }).ToList();
```

This is working fine for me to display the records in my index view.
Now ,I want to display the same records in the corresponding textboxes at the time of edit.

Comment: dear you have to use the Include keyword

Comment: check the @yasser answer it's solution for you question

Comment: If you can get the data for display you can very well use the same data for displaying records at the time of edit.

Comment: @Yasser - The problem is that from my index view I will be clicking edit for one of the records and all the datas of that record should be transferred the edit view and this is where I am facing the problem.Can u tell me how to get country name and state name from the respective tables and hence bind them in the textboxes.Or directly send all these records to the edit view....?Thanks for all of your helps..

Answer (score 3):

You could try and use `.Include()` to include reference to your related tables.

```
var items = db.TableName
              .Include("FTable1")
              .Include("FTable2")
              .Where(allcompositekeyshere).ToList();
```

[You cannot use Find directly](http://entityframework.codeplex.com/workitem/74) - Find doesn't work with includes.

Here's what the EF team says

> We have decided not to implement this because the syntax to call Find with an Include wouldn't be much simpler than the equivalent LINQ query:

```
ctx.Products.Include(p => p.Category).Single(p => p.Id == 3)
```

> Find also has logic to retrieve the entity from memory if it is already loaded. This gets very complicated if we need to pull the entity from memory but then hit the database for some or all of the related entities (or vice versa).

Comment: Thanks firstly,here I am not able to access the Items property.As soon as I enter db. I'm getting all the tables list but not getting items there,so can u please tell what this Items is?Do I need to declare anything in order to access the Items property.

Comment: Oh no.. Items is just an example. I ll change it to avoid any more confusion to TableName.

Comment: var test = db.City.Include("Country").Include("State").Where(c => c.CityID == cityID && c.CountryID == id  && c.StateID == stateID ).ToList(); Is it correct what i'm doing,because it is giving error. If yes then in my Edit view i'm having a global model which is having city,state and country properties,then how to convert this city model what i'm assigning to var test to global model.

Comment: `var test = db.City.Include("Country").Include("State").Where(c => c.CityID == cityID && c.CountryID == id && c.StateID == stateID )` may be correct only if City has foriegn key related with Country and State Tables. "Country" and "State" are tables and CityId, CountryId and StateId are all fields of the Country table. 

Are you getting compile time errors ? or runtime ?

Comment: City Table is having all the fields:CityID,StateID and CountryID

Comment: We r getting runtime error as: A specified Include path is not valid. The EntityType 'Test.CityModel' does not declare a navigation property with the name 'Country'.

Comment: The error clearly states there is no relationship between your City and Country table in your edmx. Is there one ?

Comment: Cant we join tables without relationships since city table contains both countryId and stateId which are correspondingly the primary keys.I was able to this in sql server.I just want to get all the details of City table along with CountryName from country table and stateName from state table.Can u please suggest me some way to get that.I guess I am clear with my requirement.Please let me know..

Comment: You will have to open your edmx and manually map your countryId stateId with the resective primary key of your table. This relationship if already present in your database gets reflected in your edmx while you add these tables. If not you need to manually add them.

Comment: I've updated my question and posted my linq query .Same thing I wanna get while editing.Can u pls have a look into this because I cannot map the relationsip since it will create a problem for me.Can I do this by linq query instead of using find or include which comes under EF or any other logic via which I can get all the records at the time of edit.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/52102/discussion-between-yasser-and-saroj)